# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value while adding subview

Tags: ios, swift

Below is my code to get the uiview from another nib file

```
var subviewArray=NSArray()
subviewArray=NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("RADetail", owner: self, options:nil)
if  let sview:UIView=(subviewArray.objectAtIndex(0) as? UIView){
       SV_DetailView .addSubview(sview)
     }
```

I have checked that sview is not nil . The last line of code throwing error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Comment: So, can your SV_DetailView be nil

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne SV_DetailView is a IBOUTLet of a view on xib file

Comment: But is it nil?  From the exception it seems so.  Which method are you running this code in?

Comment: "NSLog("both should not be nil %@ & %@", sview , SV_DetailView)" //paste this code above "SV_DetailView .addSubview(sview)" line

Comment: so what can be the solution for that ,  I just want to add sview as subview in SV_DetailView?

Comment: Have you connected the `SV_DetailView` outlet?

Comment: @Aderstedt yes its a outlet

Comment: What method are you running the code in?  How did you instantiate this view controller?

Comment: I think `subviewArray` is nil and calling its objectAtIndex method produce a crash. Are you sure that Nib name is correct ?